# Can vim's expression evaluation be used with existing expressions in the buffer?

Tags: vim, expression

In `vim`, we can do quick calculations in either insert or command mode by typing `<C-r>=` followed by an expression such as `1.1+2.2`, to get the result into the buffer.

If I have an existing expression in the current buffer, such as `25.22 + 14.55`, is there a way to have vim evaluate this expression, and replace it with the result?

I am primarily interested in solutions that do not use external tools, such as `bc`.

Update: To be more explicit, here is what I want on the line in the buffer before and after evaluation.

Sample Input:

```
25.22 + 14.55
```

Sample Output:

```
39.77
```

Comment: Sample input and sample output? Is the input all on one line?

Comment: @FDinoff, Let me update to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation you use `eval()` to evaluate an expression.

```
register                                                expr-register @r
--------        
...
When using the '=' register you get the expression itself, not what it
evaluates to.  Use eval() to evaluate it.
```

To pass the current line to `eval()` you can use the following.

```
:s/.*/\=eval(submatch(0))
```

which replaces the expression with the result of running eval on it.

Take a look at `:h sub-replace-expression`

Answer (score 1):

`<C-r>"`    :paste the contents of the default register into the command line.

You can use a named register to paste the content from:

`<C-r>=<C-r><register><CR>`

You can create a `macro` like the example below and run it with `@r` on required line to replace the line with the evaluated expression:

`:let @r='"ay$C^R=^Ra^M^['`

where

- `"ay$` : Yank till end of line to register `a`
- `C` : Delete the line and enter into insert mode.
- `^R=^Ra^M` : Evaluate the content of a register `a` and insert at
  current cursor position.
- `^[` : Change to command mode

Make sure you insert `Cnrl` character literally using `Ctrl-v`.
For example to insert `Ctrl-r`, press `Ctrl-V` then `Ctrl-r`.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: No need to yank! When you do deletes which don't span a whole line, you can access the deleted text in the @- register. So just `C<C-R>=<C-R>-<Enter>` should replace the line by the evaluated contents.